# How can I add a remote hook to a loopback built-in model?

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to log out whenever someone has tried to login to my app. How can I do this by adding a remote hook to the `login` method of the built-in User model?

Answer (score 0):

I added a boot script under `server/boot` to do this

```
module.exports = function(app) {
const User = app.models.User;
timestamp = new Date();
User.afterRemote('login', function (ctx, modelInstance, next) {
    console.log(ctx.req.body.email, 'has logged in at', timestamp);
    next();
});
User.afterRemoteError( 'login', function( ctx, next) {
    console.log(ctx.req.body.email, 'has unsuccessfully tried to login at', timestamp);
    next();
});
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to OP question, don't know why people downvote it. With this, you can do remote hooks to built-in User model. Above answer is if a modified built-in User model is used, then you can use the normal .js file created for that model

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Extending-built-in-models.html):

Extend the built-in User model to create your own model that represents users or customers; this model provides capabilities to register, login, and recover passwords. When you extend the built-in User model, use a model name other than “User” such as “customer,” or “client.” Don’t name it “User” because that will conflict with the built-in User model.